# What is the best way to reactivate an app running in the tray?

Tags: delphi, mutex, minimize, trayicon, invocation

I have a delphi app that runs minimized to a tray icon.  When the tray icon is double clicked the app opens a non-modal user interface form.

I have added logic to the app to detect whether it is already running.  If it isn't running, it starts up and miminizes itself to the tray.

If it is already running, I want it to pass control to the first instance of itself and open the non-modal form, and then exit (the second instance).  What's the best way to do this?

TIA
R

Comment: Really has nothing to do with the system tray.  The solution is the same if it's just a regular window, minimized.  Or open, but buried behind other windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft way is not flawless, so i do prefer old school:

```
const WM_KNOCK_KNOCK = WM_USER + 42;
{ or WM_USER + 265 or any number you like, consult PSDK documentation why WM_USER range }
{ or do RegisterWindowMessage }

{...}

procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Window: HWND;
begin 
  Window := FindWindow(PChar({MainForm.}ClassName), nil);
  { 
  i neither remember how it works exactly nor have time to investigate right now, 
  so quick and dirty validity test follows:
  }
  Assert(not (HandleAllocated and (Window = Handle)), 'failed, use fallback');
  {
  if Window <> 0 then
  begin
    PostMessage(Window, WM_KNOCK_KNOCK, 0, 0);
    Halt;
  end;

  { regular initialization }

end;
```

Now, WM_KNOCK_KNOCK message handler of first instance performs wakeup routine.

---

i have little clue what exactly you do when you receive WM_LBUTTONUP (or perhaps WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK) in your Shell_NotifyIcon wrapper (Application.Restore, maybe?). As, Chris Thornton said, there is no such state as 'minimized to tray', it is artifical.

---

Fallback: if assertion fails, note what code depends only on class function `ClassName` so could be easily moved out of `FormCreate` and invoked before Application creates it.

Comment: Almost there.  I handle the message in first instance, show the form, call BringToFront, SetFocus, but I can't get the form to show as the topmost, nor get it focused.

Comment: Hardcoding messages as wm_user + <constant> is a good way to screw yourself

Comment: presumably because there is a chance of collision with another app?  How do you get a guaranteed unique constant value then?

Comment: Speaking of "not flawless," here we have code that's quite likely to detect *itself* as the other instance, and certainly not guaranteed to find another instance of this same program. If *you* named your window class TMainForm, what's to say a dozen other developers didn't do the very same thing?

Comment: @Jherico, you don't have to worry about choosing unique message values. Since you're only sending the message to other instances of your own application's windows, you are in complete control over how the message gets handled. You just need to make sure that you really only send it to your own program; FindWindow doesn't allow you to make that guarantee, though.

Comment: @Jherico no, it is not, since i'm suggesting using WM_USER..$7FFF for exactly what it reserved for, i do not build defenses against spurious messages.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy, re: FindWindow vs. hidden window - that requires a testcase; re: dozen of Project1.exe modules showing TForm1 windows - this assumes an environment which really doesnt any more other software.

Comment: No, @User, the failure case doesn't require the EXEs to have the same name. It just requires their main forms to have the same class name. Your example used TMainForm, which in my experience is a very common choice. If another program's running using that same generic window class name, you're sunk. There's no guarantee of which window FindWindow will return when there are multiple matches, so if you call it within the OnCreate handler, there's no guarantee it won't simply find the same window you just created. There's no test case for it since there's no documented behavior to test against.

Comment: I think you can pretty much guarantee your window class name will be unique provided you rename it from "TForm1" and call it "TAardvarkMP3PlayerTrayIconHiddenMainForm" or whatever.

Comment: I have never had an instance where the application iterating through the windows has found itself rather than a first instance of the same EXE (and it had never occurred to me that might be a problem), but that's probably because I do the check before the main form is created.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy: While I have your attention do you have a solution to me earlier comment - re bringing the form to the font and giving it focus once you have found it and shown it?

Comment: @Ken assertion fails when and only when: a) window already created when constructor invokes DoFormCreate b) FindWindow locates hidden windows, please dont tell me what it is not possible to test. Also, i did not suggest to use MainForm as good name http://www.google.com/search?q=illustrative+purposes

Answer (score 5):

The [recommended](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633559(VS.85).aspx) method of detecting another instance of a given application is for that application to create a named mutex or lock a file in a well known location, so that the second instance will trigger an error when you try to create the same mutex or lock the same file.  Once you know there's another instance running, you can find the process handle for that instance and send it a message to restore if its minimized.

Comment: Make sure you call AllowSetForegroundWindow before you bring the other instance to the front.

Comment: I can't find where AllowSetForegroundWindow is declared...?

Comment: Wouldn't a named event (Windows Event object, not Delphi event method) be a better choice than a mutex? It could be used to signal the running application as well as for detecting it.

Comment: @dummzeuch: possibly, but then you have to write the handler for listening to the event.  On the other hand if you can just find the window you're trying to restore you can send it a standard window message and isolate the functionality in one place in the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
program Only_One_Mutex;

//undefine this   {.$define useMutex} to make it a multi instance app.
{$define useMutex}

uses
  Forms,
  Windows,
  Messages,
  MainForm in 'MainForm.pas' {frmMain};

{$R *.res}

{$ifdef useMutex}
var
  Mutex : THandle;
{$endif}


function pBuffStr( Var S1: String; S:String ): PChar;
begin
  FillChar(S1,SizeOf(S1),#0); {clear out the destination string}
  S1:= S+#0;                  {set it equal the source}
  Result:= @S1[1];            {result is a PChar pointer }
end;

procedure WindowToTop( WN: String );
  var
    iTitle: integer;
    S1,S  : String;
    Done: Boolean;
begin
  Done:= False;
  While NOT Done do begin
    if Pos(';',WN) > 0 then begin
      S:= Copy(WN,1,Pos(';',WN)-1);
      WN:= Copy(WN,Pos(';',WN)+1,Length(WN));
    end else begin
      S:= WN;
      Done:= True;
    end; {if Pos}
    iTitle:= FindWindow( nil, pBuffStr(S1,S) );
    if iTitle <> 0 then
      if NOT SetForegroundWindow( iTitle ) then
        GetLastError();
    Application.ProcessMessages;
  end; {while NOT Done}
end;

procedure RestoreWindow( WN: String );
  var
    iTitle: integer;
    Dest, S  : String;
    Done: Boolean;
begin
  Done:= False;
  While NOT Done do begin
    if Pos(';',WN) > 0 then begin             {is there more than ONE name}
      S:= Copy(WN,1,Pos(';',WN)-1);           {copy the first name of the original}
      WN:= Copy(WN,Pos(';',WN)+1,Length(WN)); {reduce the original string}
    end else begin
      S:= WN;                                 {only one name, so copy it}
      Done:= True;                            {this loop is done}
    end; {if Pos}
    iTitle:= FindWindow( nil, pBuffStr(Dest,S) ); {search for the window name}
    if iTitle <> 0 then                           {if found, then restore it}
      DefWindowProc(iTitle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_RESTORE, SC_RESTORE);
  end; {while NOT Done}
end;


//=================================================================

procedure AppRun;
begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.Title := 'Only One Prog';
  Application.CreateForm(TfrmMain, frmMain);
  Application.Run;
end;

begin

{$ifdef useMutex}
  //global var declarations in the mainform.
  {=====================================================================}
  //ATitle MUST match the assigned Application.Title in AppRun
  //and Application.Title can "NOT" be a constant or var.
  ATitle   := 'Only One Prog';

  { THIS IS HOW IT KEEPS THE SECOND INSTANCE FROM STARTING,
    by using a MUTEX, and a MAINFORM window title  }
  //any text appender will work.
  AMutex   := ATitle + ' Mutex Thu, Jul/12/2012';

  //mainform's caption
  ACaption := ATitle + ', Mainform Caption';

  //a label on the mainform
  ALabel   := ATitle + ', MainForm Label-using mutex';
  {=====================================================================}

  Mutex := CreateMutex(nil, True, PAnsiChar( AMutex ));
  if (GetLastError = ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS) then begin
    try
      RestoreWindow( ACaption );
      WindowToTop( ACaption );       //main form's name
    finally
      CloseHandle(Mutex);
    end;
  end else
    if  (Mutex <> 0)
    AND (GetLastError <> ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS)
    then begin
     try
       AppRun;
     finally
       CloseHandle(Mutex);
     end;
    end;
{$else}
  //global var declarations in the mainform.
  {=====================================================================}
  ATitle   := 'More than One';                  //global declaration in the mainform.
  //mainform's caption - THIS IS HOW IT KEEPS THE SECOND INSTANCE FROM STARTING
  ACaption := ATitle + ', Mainform Caption';//global declaration in the mainform.
  //a label on the mainform
  ALabel   := ATitle + ', MainForm Label-multi exe';  //global declaration in the mainform.
  {=====================================================================}
  AppRun;
{$endif}

end.


unit MainForm;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils,
  Variants, Classes, Graphics,
  Controls, Forms,   Dialogs, StdCtrls, LblEffct;


type
  TfrmMain = class(TForm)
    le1: TLabelEffect;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  frmMain: TfrmMain;

  //these GLOBAL vars, are assigned values in the program source (.dpr) file.
  ATitle,
  ACaption,
  ALabel,
  AMutex  :String;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TfrmMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Caption     := ACaption;     //used to ID this form...
  le1.Caption := ALabel;
end;

end.
```